# Adobe Campaign Workflow Result: Unable to read data from the base

Tags: postgresql, adobe, workflow

I created a workflow with a simple `query` activity, that query is executed good and returns results (Number of results is shown over the `result arrow`) without error.

When I right-click on the `result arrow` and `Display the target` the new window shows the following error:

**`Unable to read data from the base, the table has  been purged or the current workflow configuration is no longer compatible with this structure`**

Additionally, I clicked the help link `Display errors during data loading...` and I got:

```
PGS-220000 PostgreSQL error: ERROR:  relation "wkf1193360583_27_1" does not exist
LINE 1: ... || E' (' || COALESCE(R1.sEmail, '') || E')' FROM wkf1193360...
                                                             ^

WDB-200001 SQL statement 'SELECT   W0.iId, COALESCE(R1.sLastName, '') || E' ' || COALESCE(R1.sFirstName, '') || E' (' || COALESCE(R1.sEmail, '') || E')' FROM wkf1193360583_27_1 W0 JOIN NmsRecipient R1 ON (R1.iRecipientId = W0.iId) LIMIT 200' could not be executed.
BAS-010003 Unable to complete operation in current status.
```

I expect that in the new window appears the data returned by the query as a list.

Can anyone help me in order to manage that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this happens when the workflow is **finished**, to avoid that, add a `Finish` activity to the workflow then change that activity to **Unable but don't execute**, with that you can see the **Target dimension** when clicking on the arrow.

Answer (score 2):

israel,
in order to view the list of the results in **Display The Target**, you need to navigate to Workflow properties and select **Keep the result of interim populations between two executions**.  Once done, save the workflow. Refer to the screenshot. 
[image]

In this way you can see the queried results. 
Let me know if you need more help.
Best,
Imran